# OpenCV: Restore image/frame recorded during fast motion

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Is there any way to restore image which was recorded during fast motion? By restore I mean to sharpener edges, fix details, etc. I have 10-15sec long video, so I guess I can use different frames to restore single frame.

Here is an example of such image:
[image]

Comment: One common approach for motion blur is to use a [Wiener filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution) for deconvolution. Unfortunately I don't think OpenCV has an implementation so you'd need to roll your own.

Comment: OpenCV comes with weiner filter sample in samples/python2 folder. Try that...

Comment: @AbidRahmanK when I run deconvolution.py from OpenCV samples I receive the following error: ```OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.cols > 0 && src.rows > 0) in warpAffine, file /opencv-2.4.5/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 3272
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deconvolution.py", line 98, in update
    psf = motion_kernel(ang, d)
  File "deconvolution.py", line 55, in motion_kernel
    kern = cv2.warpAffine(kern, A, (sz, sz), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
cv2.error:/opencv-2.4.5/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3272: error: (-215) src.cols > 0 && src.rows > 0 in function warpAffine```

Comment: Could you please help me to figure out the reason of the error?

Comment: Nevermind, looks like it was image format - I used png, but looks like it works fine with jpeg.

Comment: It should work with almost all formats.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK although wiener filter works, I don't know length and angle of the blur, so I guess I need to apply "blind deconvolution" algorithm to it. Could you recommend one?

Comment: I know one, but it is not available in OpenCV. You will have to implement it yourself. http://cg.postech.ac.kr/research/fast_motion_deblurring/